# Model Manager in Django - No reference to model class?

Tags: python, django, reference

I'm having a hard time understanding how works a modelManager in Django 1.6.

I don't understand where is the magic that makes this code work.

In the get_queryset(self) method there is no reference whatsoever to the Book class, so how come the DahlBookManager knows that it needs to work with the Book instances when doing super(DahlBookManager, self) (no reference to Book model, and as far as I know, self refers to an object of type "DahlBookManager" and not Book).

So either there is some kind of magic, or I REALLY need to review my Python 101.
I'd be happy to have some help, thanks!

```
# First, define the Manager subclass.
class DahlBookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DahlBookManager, self).get_queryset().filter(author='Roald Dahl')

# Then hook it into the Book model explicitly.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    dahl_objects = DahlBookManager() # The Dahl-specific manager.
```

Comment: But you have associated this manager specifically to `Book` in `dahl_objects = DahlBookManager()` right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a model class in django, it calls `add_to_class` for each attribute on the model.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/db/models/base.py#L143

if what you're trying to add the class has a `contribute_to_class` method, then it gets called instead of calling `setattr`

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/db/models/base.py#L264

So when you assign the manager to the model class with

```
dahl_object = DahlBookManager()
```

`contribute_to_class()` is called on the manager class, which receives the model class. It saves this on self.model:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/models/manager.py#L69

`get_queryset()` then uses this reference to `self.model`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/models/manager.py#L123

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it much better now, still where did you get that contribute_to_class() is called on the manager class?
It still feels like magic going on under the hood :-)

Comment: I've updated the post to explain what's going on under the hood when you attach the manager to the model class. This contribute to class method is how all the model fields work, so that when you call Foo.bar instead of getting an instance of the field itself (which is what you declare), you get the value from the database.